# Kernel 3.14.1 compilation errors

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

I installed the kernel 3.14.1 and there seem to be no issues.

```
uname -r
3.14.1-031401-generic
```

However, when I try to go to the folder and try to do a make it fails. I see that multiple files are missing. any idea how I get them.

```
sudo make
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.1-031401-generic/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
```

I'm not able to understand how to solve this error. I looked up online and I'm now exhausted after spending 30 odd hours.

to check if the header files are available, I do `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-3.14.1-031401-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Maybe you need to install a headers package? It looks like you installed a kernel using a package manager, in which case: which kernel are you tring to compile? What did you do to download it? Also note there's no need to do `sudo make`, just run `make`

Comment: http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/04/install-upgrade-to-linux-kernel-3-14-1-in-linux.html
That is what i followed.

Comment: If you installed the *headers* you don't have the kernel source code, just the headers.

Comment: How do I get the kernel source code in /usr/src/linux.

Comment: sudo apt-get install linux-source tells me that the src code is already the newest version

Comment: That page instructs you to download a .deb of 3.14.1 and install it using dpkg. Your uname output shows it works. Why are you trying now to compile the kernel?

Comment: How do I get the src code in /usr/src/linxu then?

Comment: I don't use a Debian based distro. From what I can google, this package contains a tarball with the source code installed at `/usr/src/linux-source-<version>.tar.bz2`. But you don't usually build stuff as root. See [Ubuntu How to compile the kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile/), if that is what you want to do.